# Making a SOAP request in iPhone

Tags: iphone, soap

I am trying to use a SOAP web service which only returns me a date(test). But I am not able to connect with the web service. I am only receiving the WSDL from the web service but I am not able to get desired data. Following is my code in Objective C:

```
 NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
"<soap:Body>\n"
"<getDate xmlns:type=\"xsd:string\">\n"
"</getDate>\n"
"</soap:Body>\n"
"</soap:Envelope>\n";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

I want to use getDate method from the web service. How can I do that?

### Edit

The above code gives me following XML which is same as WSDL viewed in browser:

`<?xml version="1.0"?><definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="MyWebService" targetNamespace="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/"><types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/"/></types><portType name="MyWebServicePort"><operation name="getDate"><documentation>Get the server date and time</documentation><input message="tns:getDateIn"/><output message="tns:getDateOut"/></operation><operation name="getAgeString"><documentation>Get a nicely formatted string of a person's age</documentation><input message="tns:getAgeStringIn"/><output message="tns:getAgeStringOut"/></operation></portType><binding name="MyWebServiceBinding" type="tns:MyWebServicePort"><soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><operation name="getDate"><soap:operation soapAction="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/#getDate"/><input><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/"/></input><output><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/"/></output></operation><operation name="getAgeString"><soap:operation soapAction="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/#getAgeString"/><input><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/"/></input><output><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/"/></output></operation></binding><service name="MyWebServiceService"><port name="MyWebServicePort" binding="tns:MyWebServiceBinding"><soap:address location="http://10.1.6.5/gnosis2/public/wslogin/"/></port></service><message name="getDateIn"/><message name="getDateOut"><part name="return" type="xsd:string"/></message><message name="getAgeStringIn"><part name="name" type="xsd:string"/><part name="age" type="xsd:int"/></message><message name="getAgeStringOut"><part name="return" type="xsd:string"/></message></definitions>`

Comment: Thanks for posting the soap message string format it just solves my problem of formatting the soap request :)

Answer (score 0):

Veery simple way is to generate WSDL classes.
Can do that using https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/.
Folowing instruction from https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions

Answer (score 0):

The following code block helped me in handling web-service using SOAP request.

```
-(void)getWebServiceContent {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_value_here"];
    NSString *soapBody = @"soap_body_here";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPBody:[soapBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //GET
    [request addValue:@"Value_to_be_added" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,id responseObject{

        NSLog(@"Success : Content : %@",[operation responseString]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Failed");
    })];

    [operation start];
}
```