# iOS - how to make SOAP request & receive the concern response

Tags: objective-c, soap, nsurlconnection

I know htere is lot of stuff available on web for "how to use SOAP in iOS", but still I failed in doing for following SAOP Request & response. Help is greatly Appreciated.
I use the simple `NSURLConnection` for request & response
SOAP Requst

```
POST ???.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: ???
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetMessages"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetMessages xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GroupName>string</GroupName>
      <Date>dateTime</Date>
    </GetMessages>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

SOAP Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetMessagesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetMessagesResult>xml</GetMessagesResult>
    </GetMessagesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is the code I wrote for sending the request..

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<GetMessages xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<GroupName>%@</GroupName>\n"
                         "<Date>%@</Date>\n"
                         "</GetMessages>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                         , txtfield1.text
                         , textfield2.text
                         ];
NSLog(@"soapMessage: \n%@",soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"???.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/GetMessages" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if(theConnection )
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
else
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
```

I am getting this error in `connectionDidFinishLoading`

```
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.</faultstring>
     <detail />
  </soap:Fault>
```

I referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800396/making-a-soap-request-in-iphone)
&  [used the code in this link & modified according to my convenience to make it worked](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)

**My question is how to send the request & receive the concern response**

*Thanks a lot in advance*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem seems not related to the send/recv of soap messages at all BUT to the value you send as `dateTime` -- it doesn't have the correct format.

=> Server was unable to process request. ---> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

**use an NSDateFormatter to write the date string in the requested format**

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot.. It worked perfect after formatting the date &time