# Parse string from svc in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am already see that this link its very nice and working but my problem still exists.

[Making Soap request in Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800396/making-a-soap-request-in-iphone)

Please click on this link and try my service to them http://mpccservices.congressmobile.org/MPCC_DistrictAssembly.svc

```
method- wsdl:operation name="GetDistrictEnglish">
<soap:operation 
soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IMPCC_DistrictAssembly/GetDistrictEnglish" 
style="document"/>
```

and output like `~1&indore~!~ ~2&dehli~!~`... I want to that how to set area according to like indore,dehli... are set in field text and its id 1,2,3,4 are return and get area in second field according to district name.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WSDL2OBJC](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) code..  It will help you to generate the objc files for your web service..

Here is the link for [Tutorial](http://www.priyaontech.com/2012/10/soap-based-webservices-integration-in-an-ios-app/)