# How send html tag data in soap request as string parameter in iPhone programming

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, soap, encryption

I want send encrypted file to my server which will give me decrypted file as pdf in response ,but I am trying to send encrypted file to server in soap request ,but unable to get any response.encrypted  file contains xml.how can i create request with that encrypted file?Is there any limitation to send data in soap request ,Please help me,Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800396/making-a-soap-request-in-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding your values that include HTML tags to your SOAP request, replace `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;` and `&` with `&amp;`. Or you could use a `CDATA`. As [section 2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) of the XML spec says:

> The ampersand character (`&`) and the left angle bracket (`<`) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a `CDATA` section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "`&amp;`" and "`&lt;`" respectively. The right angle bracket (`>`) may be represented using the string "`&gt;`", and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either "`&gt;`" or a character reference when it appears in the string "`]]>`" in content, when that string is not marking the end of a `CDATA` section.

When the SOAP request is received, it will automatically replace those `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;` tags for you.